# Закрыть окно FireFox'а

Tags: firefox

Я так понимаю закрыть окно FireFox'а ни JS, ни PHP - нет реализации ни какой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Представьте себе назойливый рекламный сайт, способный закрывать все другие окна, тем самым перемещая фокус на себя, тогда необходимость ограничения JS телом документа в целях безопасности станут понятными. Это по поводу JS.
PHP - вовсе серверная технология, которая со стороны клиента не видна.

Возможно, какой-то расширенный функционал можно реализовать в виде браузерного плагина. Основной язык разработки для Firefox, кстати, JS.